# Output multiple results of a single query to a single text file with the same format

Tags: powershell

I am performing Audits of Servers and sending the results to text files. One of the things I need is a list of the Serial ports currently configured on a server.
I am using:

```
Get-PnpDevice -Class 'Ports' | Select-Object -Property Friendlyname
```

I get back exactly what I need on the display

```
FriendlyName                                      
------------                                      
Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM9)           
Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM10)          
Digi One SP - Port 1 (COM4)                       
Standard RealPort Device TS4 - Port 2 (COM14)     
Standard RealPort Device TS4 - Port 1 (COM13)     
Intel(R) Active Management Technology - SOL (COM3)
Standard RealPort Device TS4 - Port 4 (COM16)     
USB Serial Port (COM11)                           
Standard RealPort Device TS4 - Port 3 (COM15)     
USB Serial Port (COM 6)
```

When I send to a text file I get nothing.

```
$Port = Get-PnpDevice -Class 'Ports' | Select-Object -Property Friendlyname 
"Serial Ports:       " +  $Port >> C:\Audit\Audit.txt
```

How do I get the data, in the same format as the display, to a text file?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Out-String` to turn the on-screen output into a raw string - which is then easily written to disk with `Set-Content` or `Out-File`:

```
Get-PnpDevice -Class 'Ports' |Select-Object -Property Friendlyname |Out-String |Set-Content .\path\to\output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you! that did work. I used the following:
**$SPort = Get-PnpDevice -Class 'Ports' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Friendlyname |Out-String**

then
**"Serial Ports:       " +  $Sport >> C:\Spok_Messenger_Audit\Audit.txt**